# How to build a DQN that outputs 1 discrete and 1 continuous value as a pair?

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, dqn

I am building a DQN for an Open Gym environment. My observation space is only 1 discrete value but my actions are:

```
self.action_space = (Discrete(3), Box(-100, 100, (1,)))
```

ex: [1,56], [0,24], [2,-78]...

My current neural network is:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu', input_shape=states)) # (1,)
model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='linear'))
```

(I copied it from a tutorial that only outputs 1 discrete value in the range [0,1]}

I understand that I need to change the last layer of my neural network but what would it be in my case?

My guess is that the last layer should have 3 binary outputs and 1 continuous output but I don't know
if it is possible to have different natures of outputs within the same layer.

Comment: I was told that the training of multi dimentional output models grows exponentially with the number of outputs. I am going to stick to single output discrete values.

Comment: In addition to that, it doesn't seem to be possible to train DQN using a continuous action space which makes sense indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already noted in your comment, DQN is not compatible with continuous action spaces because of how DQN works; `argmax of "a" for Q(s,a)` - It's impossible to check `Q(s,a)` for all `a` when `a` is continuous.

---

Having said that, when applying this to **Policy Gradient** methods (which *are* compatible with continuous action spaces) you will run into the same issue in your question because with policy gradient you need to provide a probability for each action that you take. Something like this could work:

- Actor (a neural net in this case) gives 3 outputs.
- First 2 outputs are probabilities of each discrete value.
- 3rd output is your continuous value.

Take the softmax of the first two outputs which gives you your discrete value and then take the third output which is continuous and this will give you your action. You then need to derive the probability of that action which is given by the combined probability of all of your outputs.